# angular-dynamic-locale works incorrect on android

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, ionic-framework

angular-dynamic-locale works fine on browser,but does not work well on android(I use ionic to develop a hybrid mobile app).the tmhDynamicLocale.set('en') return a promise that enters error function.Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you add the code you use, and the error you receive?

Comment: sorry,i didn't make it clear,it's tmhDynamicLocale.set('zh-CN'),my language setting is Chinese .It's complicate,i do exactly as the instructions(https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale). when i use anywhere to run the program on my computer,it works well.But when i install the program on my android mobile,it just show 'zh-CN' as the error message.

Comment: `angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova','tmh.dynamicLocale'])

.controller('startCtrl',function($scope,tmhDynamicLocale,$locale){
    tmhDynamicLocale.set(navigator.language).then(function(success){
    alert('success---'+angular.toJson(success));
  },
  function(error){
    alert('error---'+angular.toJson(error));
  });

  $scope.today = new Date();

})`

Comment: html`{{today| date:'MMMM yyyy'}}` when i run it by anywhere ,it shows ‘一月 2016',when i run it on my mobile ,it shows 'January 2016',both language setting is Chinese

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you posted the error message.

**My guess:**

I noticed that you used `zh-CN` instead of `zh-cn`. On android, usually the internal storage system is EXT4, which is **case sensitive**. `angular-dynamic-locale` doesn't do case conversions so it tries to look for the `angular-locale_zh-TW.js` and might not find it (should be  `angular-locale_zh-tw.js`).

**Solution:**

Just do `tmhDynamicLocale.set('zh-cn')`

See if that works.